# isEqualToString not evaluating true

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdata

Method:

```
- (void)serverResponse:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
    NSLog(@"%i", [response isEqualToString:@"1"]);
}
```

Log:

```
2015-03-15 06:26:53.716 appName[687:60b] 1                            
2015-03-15 06:26:53.718 appName[687:60b] 0
```

This doesn't seem to make any sense. I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the encoding, but I'm not sure what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Log `data` and log `[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: logged data and saw the 20's for whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing strings, `NSString` does not take encoding into account.

Your problem is simple: The response contains 28 spaces after the "1".

Two possible solutions:

```
BOOL integerValueEquality = [response integerValue] == 1;
```

or

```
NSString *trimmedString = [response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
BOOL stringEquality = [trimmedString isEqualToString:@"1"];
```

Comment: I thought I removed all the ?> tags in my php, but there was one left over. Thanks.